# Adjusting the values of Pt_ and RXThresh_ variables for changing transmission range

Tags: ns2

I am writing a new protocol. In which I have to change(increase and decrease) transmission range of nodes.

Now I want to know,

1. how I can hack into ns-2 to change transmission and reception range.
2. how can i write code to change the range during run time?

NB: From "indep-utils/propagation/threshold.cc", I have calculated the required values of "Pt_" and "RXThresh_"

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code in your TCL. By changing **CSThresh_ and RXThresh_** values you can modify your nodes transmission range.

```
Phy/WirelessPhy set CPThresh_ 100.0
Phy/WirelessPhy set CSThresh_ 4.21756e-11 ;#transmission range
Phy/WirelessPhy set RXThresh_ 4.4613e-10 ;#transmission range
Phy/WirelessPhy set bandwidth_ 512kb
Phy/WirelessPhy set Pt_ 0.2818
Phy/WirelessPhy set freq_ 2.4e+9
Phy/WirelessPhy set L_ 1.0
```

Comment: I may be failed to clear my question. I want to hack ns-2, so that I can change the range during run time.Not at the start of the simulation.